# Read from text file and store each value in separate arrays in c++

Tags: c++, arrays, file

I am trying to read the following contents:

```
rima    doha    44881304    20  30  10  10  20  10102   10102
andrew  ny      123456      12  12  13  14  15  01020   03040
```

and store them in separate arrays, edit them, then store again into the same file.

Here is my attempted code:

```
ifstream infile;
infile.open("D:\\customers.txt");
string names[100];
string addresses[100];
int tn[100];
int numCalls[100];
int trunkCalls[100];
int numMobCalls[100];
int isdnNum[100];
int dueD[100];
int paymentD[100];

int numOfPpl = 0;

int numOfPpl = 0;

for(int i=0; i<100; i++){
        infile >> names[i] >> addresses[i]>>tn[i]>>numCalls[i]>>trunkCalls[i]>> numMobCalls[i]>> isdnNum[i]>>dueD[i]>>paymentD[i];
        numOfPpl++;
}

//Code where some values were edited



ofstream outfile("D:\\customers.txt");


for(int i=0; i<numOfPpl; i++)
{
    outfile<<names[i] << "\t" <<addresses[i] << "\t" <<tn[i]<<"\t" <<numCalls[i]<<"\t" 
        <<trunkCalls[i]<<"\t"<<numMobCalls[i]<<"\t"<<numMobCalls[i]<<"\t"<<isdnNum[i]<<"\t"<<dueD[i]<<"\t"<<paymentD[i]<<endl;
}

outfile.close();
infile.close();
```

Issue is that the first two lines are stored correctly, but then there are random values in the file. How do I fix this?

Comment: How many lines are there in the files ?

Comment: You are probably getting garbage values, are they large negative numbers? I would assume you are having problems because you are looping i -> 100 so if there are not 100 lines in the file the lines that are empty are going to be garbage values.

Comment: Please, not another one.  Have you searched StackOverflow for "c++ read file columns"?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There's a couple things wrong with your code.

First, you declare numOfPpl twice.  Get rid of the 2nd count.

Secondly, you have 9 input categories (names, addresses, etc.), but your text file has 10 per line. This will throw the entire program off.

The third issue is are you going to have exactly 100 lines in the customers.txt?  If not, you should utilize a command to peek to the next line to make sure if there's another line below.  Using a while or do/while loop would probably be better if there aren't 100 lines in your text file.  Something like

```
while(infile){
   // retrieve your data
   infile.peek();
}
```

or utilizing the for loop

```
for(int i = 0; infile; i++){
   // retrieve your data
   infile.peek();
}
```

would probably be a better loop.  Again, if you're not going to have 100 lines, the for loop will give you the null output because there isn't any data being put into the array elements. I believe that should correct your issues.

Another thing you should watch out for is having an extra space at the end of a line.  That'll throw your program output off as well.